# React : Listen for device (API endpoint)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, listener

I've a device (SMSMachine) who have only one endpoint API.
My goal is to listen for all the asynchronous device communication, that the device do automatically as well as the response of a API call with parameters for sending SMS for example.

I've try with this code (snippet) where I pass the user/password parameter:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        try{
            const response = await fetch(`goip_get_status.html`, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${username}:${password}`)
                }})
                
            const json= await response.json();
                
            if (response.ok && response.status === 200) {
                console.log("Connection made ", response);
            } else if (response.status >= 400 && response.status < 500 && response.status !== 429) 
            {
                console.log("Client side error ", response);
            }
            console.log("response:",response);
            console.log("json:",json);

            const parsedData = JSON.parse(json.data);
            setData((data) => [...data, parsedData]);
                
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log("error: ",error);
        }
    };
    fetchData();
}, [data]);
```

But I receive "access restricted" message.

Finally I think that is not the correct approach.
Anyone have similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solutions.

I see that the device , after many failed attemptto to login, block the IP for some minutes, so the device response "access restricted".

To solve the issue I've put also

```
        params: { 
        username: username,
        password: password,
    },
```

(with the correct username and password)
on the parameters passed to fetch like this:

```
     const response = await fetch(`goip_get_status.html`, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${username}:${password}`)
            }
            params: { 
                username: username,
                password: password,
            },
            }
```